# External linking with AMP

Tags: amp-html

We own and manage a few websites, we have a list of our websites on our normal html site but we aren't able to get AMP to send to external url.

Have tried using JSON with the amp-list parameter as follows:

```
<amp-list width="auto"
  height="100"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="https://test.com/amp/test.json"
  class="m1">
  <template type="amp-mustache"
    id="amp-template-id">
    <div>
      <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    </div>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

The link shows on the AMP page but when you click on the link it just goes to the home page of the html site.

The JSON file contains:

```
{
 "items": [
   {
     "title": "Domain Name",
     "url": "http://want.you"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: is `https://test.com` CORS enabled? And `http://want.you` needs to be `HTTPS` and CORS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSON ENDPOINT URL is CORS Enable and add library for amp-list. below code is working in AMP playground.

```html
<!--
  ## Introduction

  The [`amp-list`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) component fetches dynamic content from a CORS JSON endpoint and renders it using a supplied template. This is good for embedding a dynamic list of related articles.
-->
<!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-list</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- Import the `amp-list` component ... -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <!-- ... and the `amp-mustache` component in the header -->
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <style amp-custom>

  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <amp-list width="auto"
  height="100"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="https://api.myjson.com/bins/pxnd8"
  class="m1">
  <template type="amp-mustache"
    id="amp-template-id">
    <div>
      <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    </div>
  </template>
</amp-list>


</body>
</html>
```